# Remix: Gas required exceeds allowance or always failing transaction

Tags: solidity, contract-development, transactions, remix, contract-debugging

I have a contract which has transferFrom function

```
    mapping(address => uint) balances;

    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint)) allowed;

    mapping (address => bool) public frozenAccount;

   // Transfer token from spender account to receiver account
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) {
        require(!transactionLock);         // Check for transaction lock
        require(!frozenAccount[from]);     // Check if sender is frozen
        require(!frozenAccount[to]);       // Check if recipient is frozen
        balances[from] = balances[from].sub(tokens);
        allowed[from][msg.sender] = allowed[from][msg.sender].sub(tokens);
        balances[to] = balances[to].add(tokens);
        emit Transfer(from, to, tokens);
        return true;
    }
```

When i execute this function i am getting error :

> Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The
>   transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
>
> gas required exceeds allowance or always failing transaction

I have read many answers in StackOverflow . No solution work for me

Comment: how is the `transactionLock` defined? is that set to `false`?

Comment: yes it is initailized to `false` in constructor

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the account `from` has not *allowed* the `to` account to withdraw funds.
I recommend to add some extra verifications:

```
  function transferFrom(
    address from,
    address to,
    uint256 tokens
  )
    public
    returns (bool)
  {
    require(!transactionLock);         // Check for transaction lock
    require(!frozenAccount[from]);     // Check if sender is frozen
    require(!frozenAccount[to]);       // Check if recipient is frozen

    require(tokens <= _balances[from]);
    require(tokens <= _allowed[from][msg.sender]);
    require(to != address(0));

    _balances[from] = _balances[from].sub(tokens);
    _balances[to] = _balances[to].add(tokens);
    _allowed[from][msg.sender] = _allowed[from][msg.sender].sub(tokens);
    emit Transfer(from, to, tokens);
    return true;
  }
```

Also, make sure that the `from` account allows the `to` account to withdraw the `tokens` amount and it should work

Comment: I am following this link for this contract. https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/ERC20_Token_Standard

Comment: When i am executing the same code with javascriptVM . it gives me this error

 `The constructor should be payable if you send value`.

Comment: the `transferFrom()` function I gave you is the one from openZeppelin: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol

plus your added modifications

Comment: Is there any restriction in choosing these from and to address OR i can use any address . I have sent some token to from address and to address is a new address which has no token. when i make transaction it gives this error .

Comment: you can use **any address**, but before calling the `transferFrom(from, to, amount)`, you also have to call `approve(to, amount)`, from the above **from** address.

Comment: How can i call `approve(to,amount)` method from `from` address. my `from` address is a random address that i took from etherscan. I have called approve method from remix ui and tried to make transfer . i am getting same error

Comment: you can't call `approve()` from a random address. You have to call it **from the address that has the tokens**. That address **has to be under your control** (to be able to sign transactions with it).

Comment: It does not work :( 

I deployed contract using my coinbase address . I sent some token to address A . now i change account from my coinbase to A .Now i first called approve method on address B to receive 10 Token . then i called transferFrom( A's address,B's address, 10). I got the same warning and did a transaction i got hash . but did not got balance in B